# How do I prevent inset shadow to disappear upon scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to show an inset shadow in a table.
The problem is that it disappears upon scrolling.
Is there a way to prevent it from disappearing when scrolling?

[image]

As can be seen in above image, the shadow is only shown there were there is no table. The shadow seems to fall behind the table

```css
table {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  /*border-top: solid 5px;*/
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(148, 148, 148, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(148, 148, 148, 1);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(148, 148, 148, 1);
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #cacaca;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

th {
  background-color: #dce0e3;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
      <td>Maria Anders</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Centro comercial</td>
      <td>Francisco Chang</td>
      <td>Mexico</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ernst Handel</td>
      <td>Roland Mendel</td>
      <td>Austria</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Island Trading</td>
      <td>Helen Bennett</td>
      <td>UK</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Laughing Bacchus </td>
      <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
      <td>Canada</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Magazzini Alimentari </td>
      <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
      <td>Italy</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't quite see what you are seeing.  On the browsers I've looked at this on, the only inset shadow appears to the right of the table, but not in the table itself.

Comment: In both, chrome and FF, the inset shadow seems to fall behind the table, and is therefore not shown

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the shadow to a wrapper that contains the scrollable area to preserve it.

```css
.wrapper {
  box-shadow: inset 0 2px 2px silver;
}

.scrollable {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 250px;
}

.content {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="scrollable">
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot put a box shadow on the table itself, I present two somewhat hacky solutions!

**Solution 1**: put inside the `th`

```css
table {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  /*border-top: solid 5px;*/
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #cacaca;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

th {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 5px 5px -5px rgba(148, 148, 148, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 5px 5px -5px rgba(148, 148, 148, 1);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 5px 5px -5px rgba(148, 148, 148, 1);
  background-color: #dce0e3;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
      <td>Maria Anders</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Centro comercial</td>
      <td>Francisco Chang</td>
      <td>Mexico</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ernst Handel</td>
      <td>Roland Mendel</td>
      <td>Austria</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Island Trading</td>
      <td>Helen Bennett</td>
      <td>UK</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Laughing Bacchus </td>
      <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
      <td>Canada</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Magazzini Alimentari </td>
      <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
      <td>Italy</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Solution 2**: put it onto a floating `div`

```css
table {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  /*border-top: solid 5px;*/
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.shadow {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  height: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 5px 5px -5px rgba(148, 148, 148, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 5px 5px -5px rgba(148, 148, 148, 1);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 5px 5px -5px rgba(148, 148, 148, 1);
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #cacaca;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

th {
  background-color: #dce0e3;
}
```

```html
<div class=shadow></div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
      <td>Maria Anders</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Centro comercial</td>
      <td>Francisco Chang</td>
      <td>Mexico</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ernst Handel</td>
      <td>Roland Mendel</td>
      <td>Austria</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Island Trading</td>
      <td>Helen Bennett</td>
      <td>UK</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Laughing Bacchus </td>
      <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
      <td>Canada</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Magazzini Alimentari </td>
      <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
      <td>Italy</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```